# AS2 Quiz Images

Tags: image, actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

This is a quiz engine that I've built (feel free to use it). I wanted to expand on it by adding images, I've never really done anything much other than variables and can't figure how to work it, I thought this would work:

```
 onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    **pic._currentframe = (index1 + 1);**
};
```

There is a movieclip called "pic"; it's full of bitmaps that hint the answers. "pic" won't change when index does, it just... does nothing.

```
answer = new Array();
    answer[0] = ["okey dokey"];
    answer[1] = ["sample", "sample1"]
    question = new Array();
    question[0] = "Type 'Okey Dokey'";
    question[1] = "Sample?";
    index1 = 0;

    onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
        **pic._currentframe = (index1 + 1;**
    };

    onEnterFrame = function ()
    {
        question_txt.text = question[index1];
    };

    enter1.onRelease = function()
    {
        question_txt.text = question[index1];
        var correct = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < answer[index1].length; i++)
        {
            if (answer_input.text.indexOf(prevEntry) == -1)
            {
                if (answer_input.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(answer[index1][i]) >= 0)
                {
                    correct = true;

                }
            }
            if (answer_input.text == "admin")
            {
                correct = true;
            }
        }

        if (correct)
        {
            index1++;
            prevEntry = answer_input.text;
            answer_input.text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            answer_input.text = "incorrect";
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens because `_currentFrame` is a read-only property. Use [`gotoAndStop(index1 + 1)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001274.html) instead.

Additionally, you should rewrite

```
onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    **pic._currentframe = (index1 + 1;**
};

onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    question_txt.text = question[index1];
};
```

to

```
onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    pic.gotoAndStop(index1 + 1);
    question_txt.text = question[index1];
};
```

because the second onEnterFrame part was overriding the first

Comment: That changes the stage's frame though?

Comment: You have to call it on the MovieClip you want to control. So use pic.gotoAndStop(index1 + 1); in your case.

Comment: onEnterFrame = function ()
{
 pic.gotoAndStop(index1 + 1);
};

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. AS3 tells you if a function is used twice doesn't it?

Comment: AS3 will prevent you from defining a function twice, but it won't prevent you from assigning a variable (holding a function) twice -- and that is what you were doing here. The whole system of using onEnterFrame is different in AS3 by the way - it uses events and listeners for those events.